# Prevent laptop from going to sleep when I close the lid, but only if I'm connected to an external display

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, external-display

When I'm connected to an external display, I would like to close the laptop without it going to sleep. When I'm *not* connected to an external display, I would like to have closing the lid put the laptop to sleep. I know I can achieve this by manually switching the power settings, but I'd like something automatic. I'm running Windows 7 (Home Premium 64bit) on an HP Pavilion dm3-1030us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script or service, that detects if an external display is connected.
If it is, have the script/service turn on sleep setting.
If it is not, have the script/service turn off sleep setting again.

Other than that I am not aware of a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Go to control panel then power settings the option should be in there

Comment: I've already checked there. It only differentiates between plugged in and on battery. There is nothing about being connected to an external display.

Comment: why dont you set up 2 power plans? its not automatic but its the best you can do